# Retry of dataproc cluster creation in Airflow 1.10

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

Hello all I need some help is Airflow.We use Airflow 1.10.We have a requirement where we want to retry the task of creating and deleting the dataproc cluster if the task fails.We do have retry parameter in Airflow 2.0 but we do not have any such parameter which retry's creating and deleting the cluster in airflow 1.10.Can anyone suggest any alternative so that if creation or deletion of dataproc cluster fails ,then we can retry creating it.

Comment: Any operator has retries. It's parameter of `BaseOperator`.

Comment: @EladKalif Do you mean that any parameter that is available in Base operator can be used as part of any other operator.Can you provide a example syntax for creation of dataproc cluster with retry parameter in airflow 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataprocCreateClusterOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2722c42659100474b21aae3504ee4cbe24f72ab4/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L387) has [`retry`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2722c42659100474b21aae3504ee4cbe24f72ab4/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L422) parameter:

> ```
> :param retry: A retry object used to retry requests. If ``None`` is specified, requests will not be
>     retried.
> ```

This ability was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6371) and available for Airflow>=1.10

If you are using Airflow<2.0:
You will need to :

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

If you are using Airflow>=2.0:
You will need to :

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

Then you can import the operator as:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateClusterOperator
```

and use it as:

```
create_cluster_operator = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    cluster_name="test",
    ...,
    retry=YOUR_RETRY_VALUE
    timeout=YOUR_TIMEOUT_VALUE
)
```

Note that all Airflow operators inherits from `BaseOperator` which has [`retries`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2722c42659100474b21aae3504ee4cbe24f72ab4/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L451-L452) parameter:

> ```
> :param retries: the number of retries that should be performed before
>     failing the task
> ```

Don't be confused between `retry` and `retries`.